# Hyper Ledger Node SDK Rest Server building in Windows 10 Issue

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Guys can any one help me that. Can we create rest server in windows OS?. I have successfully created ad installed chain code in aws. Just I want to query it in windows local using node sdk.

I successfully installed chain-code in aws managed block chain using Linux server.
 Now I want transact with chain code using fabric node JS SDK via windows 10 OS locally. I am trying it but it is not working.

May I know can we achieve this task using windows 10 or not?
If yes can I have the solution please.

I have created all the connection file and all properly, But not getting where I missed. Same process if I try in Linux ec2 instance is working, but it is not working in windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, I did it too.

The only important thing is that the Hyperledger network runs on Linux. But your Node SDK can run on Windows too.

Just create a connection profile pointing to the Linux AWS Machine with the network installed and start the server with

```
node BlockchainServerName.js
```

And you should see your server running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. use Node sdk in windows what and all we need to setup. please can you help me for this. it will be great help for me.

Comment: I am using aws cloud ec2 instance. I am not using local linux instance

Comment: This should be another question. Please set my answer as correct.